# Can't read the SOAP information without the ns2: on the tag. Why?

Tags: xml, spring, soap, xsd, wsdl

I'm trying to receive some informations from a SOAP call. My endpoint is called successfully, but the information inside my classes are `null`. I can receive the information only if I change the `<XYZFullDesc`/`<order_no>` to `<ns2:XYZFullDesc`/`<ns2:order_no>`, but I need to receive the XML **without any changes**.

The entire XML that my Soap Service need to receive:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Header/>
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:publishXYZFullModifyUsingXYZFullDesc xmlns:ns2="http://www.oracle.com/retail/igsla/integration/services/XYZFullPublishingService/v1">
         <XYZFullDesc xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/XYZFullDesc/v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <order_no>2445460</order_no>
         </XYZFullDesc>
       </ns2:publishXYZFullModifyUsingXYZFullDesc>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

My current XSD is:

```
<s:schema xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:tns="http://www.oracle.com/retail/igsla/integration/services/XYZFullPublishingService/v1"
           targetNamespace="http://www.oracle.com/retail/igsla/integration/services/XYZFullPublishingService/v1"
          elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <s:element name="publishXYZFullModifyUsingXYZFullDesc">
        <s:complexType>
            <s:sequence>
                <s:element name="XYZFullDesc" type="tns:XYZFullDesc"/>
            </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
    </s:element>

    <s:complexType name="XYZFullDesc">
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="order_no" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>

</s:schema>
```

My Spring endpoint:

```
private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.oracle.com/retail/igsla/integration/services/XYZFullPublishingService/v1";

@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "publishXYZFullModifyUsingXYZFullDesc")
@ResponsePayload
public void receberPedidoRequest(@RequestPayload PublishXYZFullModifyUsingXYZFullDesc request) {
    // code...
}
```

So what explain this behavior with the presence/absence of `ns2`? How read the XML above without any changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up with the follow solution.

As I would like to have two namespaces on the same schema, so as understand reading abut the subject, the `import` was necessary on my XSD. My original idea was set different namespaces, but I could only set a namespace for `PublishXYZFullModifyUsingXYZFullDesc` and make the namespace for `XYZFullDesc` be ignored (not empty, what is considered invalid), using [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296668/nesting-xml-elements-from-different-namespaces-in-xsd).

The main XSD:

```
<s:schema xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:po="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/XYZFullDesc/v1"
           targetNamespace="http://www.oracle.com/retail/abcd/integration/services/XYZFullPublishingService/v1"
          elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <s:import schemaLocation="po.xsd"
               namespace="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/XYZFullDesc/v1" />

    <s:element name="publishXYZFullModifyUsingXYZFullDesc">
        <s:complexType>
            <s:sequence>
                <s:element ref="po:XYZFullDesc"/>
            </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
    </s:element>

</s:schema>
```

The imported po.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<s:schema targetNamespace="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/XYZFullDesc/v1"
           xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/XYZFullDesc/v1"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <s:element name="XYZFullDesc" type="XYZFullDesc"/>

    <s:complexType name="XYZFullDesc">
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="order_no" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>

</s:schema>
```

The generated Java stubs:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "xyzFullDesc"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "publishXYZFullModifyUsingXYZFullDesc", namespace = "http://www.oracle.com/retail/abcd/integration/services/XYZFullPublishingService/v1")
public class PublishXYZFullModifyUsingXYZFullDesc {

    @XmlElement(name = "XYZFullDesc", required = true) // no namespace, but works for me
    protected XYZFullDesc xyzFullDesc;

}
```